# O que fazer com a tag [import]?

Tags: debate, tag-específica, tags-sinônimas

A tag [import](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import) não tem wiki de tag e nem fragmento de recomendação. Pelo o uso, percebi que está sendo destinada a importação de arquivos, de bibliotecas e DLLs.

A recomendação de uso da tag [importação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/importa%c3%a7%c3%a3o) segue a mesma linha, embora tenha um fragmento de recomendação:

> Tag utilizada para se referir à importação de modo geral(importação de base de dados, de arquivos, de bibliotecas, etc).

O que dá a entender que as duas são sinônimas, pelo menos ao meu ver. São sinônimas?

Answer (score 3):

Por mim, nenhuma das duas serve para nada e ambas podem ser mandadas para o cemitério das tags.

Importação é um termo genérico que só tem sentido se a linguagem de programação em questão for levada em conta, assim como a palavra-chave `import`. Entretanto, não tem muito sentido ter as tags [import-java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import-java), [import-c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import-c%23), [import-python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import-python), [import-xpto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import-xpto) e nem [importação-java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/importa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-java), [importação-c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/importa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-c%23), [importação-python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/importa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-python), [importação-xpto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/importa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-xpto).

Essas tags não servem para organizar nada e nem para localizar questões mais facilmente. Também não vislumbro nenhuma forma de salvar essas tags e torná-las úteis, e portanto elas não servem e provavelmente nunca servirão para nada.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que não porque uma é uma palavra- chave que tem uma semântica específica e a outra é uma atividade que a aplicação pode fazer.

Descrição ruim e uso errado é algo que pode-se tentar melhorar.